# Remove title bar in Python 3 Tkinter Toplevel

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm trying to create a static Toplevel window with some text and no title bar with Tkinter in Python 3.6.1 on OS X 10.12.5. I believe that `wm_overrideredirect(True)` is the method I need to achieve this, but whenever I enter this line, the Toplevel window is not displayed. When I remove this line, the Toplevel is displayed (with a title bar).

What am I doing wrong!? This is the code I have.

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

tw = tk.Toplevel()
tw.wm_overrideredirect(True)              # Toplevel will not display due to this line
tk.Label(tw, text='Some text').pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Slight error. Try `tw.overrideredirect(True)`

Comment: Which operating system are you using? [wm_overrideredirect](http://epydoc.sourceforge.net/stdlib/Tkinter.Wm-class.html#wm_overrideredirect) should work as well.

Comment: Post edited, OS X 10.12.5. I have tried both variants of the method, same difference.

Comment: My mistake, wm_overrideredirect is correct. To your issue, there have been several posts recently regarding removing window decorations in OS X. Works fine in Windows and Linux. You may already know this, but this function tells the window manager to ignore the window, in addition to appearance changes. Ignoring the window means that focus-in and focus-out events are not sent to your window (you can't bind on them), you can't raise (lift), or lower them. What you can try though is `tw.withdraw` then `tw.deiconify` to see if it will raise the window to a visible state.

Comment: Got it! `withdraw()` and `deiconify()` did nothing visible but `lift()` was the trick. Thanks!

Comment: @RonNorris when I apply  `_window.overrideredirect(True)` to the Topevel am not able to move it around.